# How to display Icon from package using name from String?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display Icon based on it's name parsed from external source. Now i have several newsfeeds integrated in app, like this:

```
myPages.add(new Subpage(0, "Main", FontAwesome5Regular.newspaper, "http://url.one"));
myPages.add(new Subpage(1, "Buses", MaterialCommunityIcons.bus_multiple, "http://url.one"));
```

where 3-d argument of SubPage constructor is IconData. 
I want to generate so much pages as needed, based on CSV.  I want to place in CSV lines like

```
    0, Main, FontAwesome5Regular.newspaper, "http://url.one"
    1, Buses, MaterialCommunityIcons.bus_multiple, "http://url.two"
```

I have no problems with parsing csv, but I don't understand how to convert parsed String "FontAwesome5Regular.newspaper" to IconData needed by constructor of Subpage.

It would be great to get solution without async/await, catching error, etc, cause I'm really sure, that CSV contains no errors, all strings are valid, all classes are available

Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: create Map<String, IconData>

Comment: It will work for limited Icons and Strings. But I want to use unlimited pages with any available IconData in flutter_vector_icons/flutter_vector_icons.dart

Comment: Can you change your CSV? Let's say you want to send an umbrella icon. Rather than "MaterialIcons.beach_access" send "MaterialIcons" in one column and "60222" in another. Parse the 60222 into a int: `var codePoint = int.parse(cp);` and make your icon as `var icon = IconData(codePoint, fontFamily: ff);`

Comment: Great! Thanks for it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

great workaroud from  Richard Heap:

Can you change your CSV? Let's say you want to send an umbrella icon. Rather than "MaterialIcons.beach_access" send "MaterialIcons" in one column and "60222" in another. Parse the 60222 into a int: var codePoint = int.parse(cp); and make your icon as var icon = IconData(codePoint, fontFamily: ff); 
– Richard Heap 2 hours ago

Answer (score 0):

You could use 'dart:mirrors' library for that, but, unfortunately, library isn't available   in flutter, so you can't access classes' static properties using their names as string. You can do it like this:

```dart
IconData getIconData(String str) {
  switch (str) {
    case "FontAwesome5Regular.newspaper": return FontAwesome5Regular.newspaper;
    case "MaterialCommunityIcons.bus_multiple": return MaterialCommunityIcons.bus_multiple;
    default: return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think about it, but i would like to use any name from huge flutter_vector_icons/flutter_vector_icons.dart package..